# Command not found after I installed foreman

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman

I am trying to use foreman locally before send it to heroku.

I ran this line to install foreman npm install -g foreman

[image]

I get command not found

[image]

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this​:

```
gem install foreman
```